# CuDNN 6 install fails due to CUDA 9.0 reference

Tags: cuda

I want to use Tensorflow with GPU. Therefore I uninstalled CUDA 9 and installed CUDA 8. Now I want to install CUDNN6.

However running this

```
sudo dpkg -i libcudnn6_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb
```

Gives the following output:

```
Preparing to unpack libcudnn6_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcudnn6 (6.0.21-1+cuda8.0) over (6.0.21-1+cuda8.0) ...
Setting up libcudnn6 (6.0.21-1+cuda8.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.7 is not a symbolic link
```

How can I solve this?